# Как в SVN перенести группу фиксаций из одного репозитория в другой?

Tags: svn

Разработка функционального модуля велась в репозитории №1 (личный репозиторий), было сделано 40 фиксаций. Возникла потребность перенести **ВСЮ** информацию по модулю с сохранением истории изменений в репозиторий №2 (командный репозиторий).

Вариант "Перенести рабочую копию от последней фиксации и приложить журнал (log)" не интересен, так как теряется история изменений отдельных файлов. Хочется именно физически переместить информацию, а не использовать внешнее включение (external).

Есть ли какой-то клиент SVN, имеющий встроенные средства, чтобы автоматически поочередно выгружать из репозитория №1 указанные фиксации, и тут же добавлять их в репозиторий №2?

Используются Visual SVN Server 2.5 и TortoiseSVN 1.8. Оба репозитория расположены на одном сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Если у вас нет локального доступа к командному репозиторию, то [используйте стандартную утилиту svnrdump,](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnrdump/) которая устанавливается вместе с VisualSVN Server. Интересующая вас команда выглядит следующим образом:

> `svnrdump dump https://server1.com/svn/MY-REPOSITORY | svnrdump load https://server2.com/svn/TEAM-REPOSITORY`
>
> `* Dumped revision 0.`
>
> `* Dumped revision 1.`
>
> `* Loaded revision 0.`
>
> `* Loaded revision 1.`
>
> `* Dumped revision 2.`
>
> `* Dumped revision 3.`
>
> `* Dumped revision 4.`
>
> `...`

- Важным условием для того, чтобы это сработало, [является непустой pre-revprop-change хук,](http://www.saas-secure.com/svn-hosting/svn-dump-restore.html) установленный для репозитория TEAM-REPOSITORY. Его достаточно установить в `'exit 0'`.
- Если вы хотите, чтобы новые ревизии заливались не в корень репозитория, в какую-то подпапку в нем, то вам нужно будет заменить `https://server2.com/svn/TEAM-REPOSITORY` на, соответственно, `https://server2.com/svn/TEAM-REPOSITORY/path/within/repository`.
- Если у вас есть локальный доступ к обоим репозиториям, то все еще проще:

> `svnadmin dump C:\Repositories\MY-REPOSITORY | svnadmin load C:\Repositories\TEAM-REPOSITORY`
>
> Для того, чтобы ревизии заливались в какую-то подпапку репозитория в этом варианте можно использовать [опцию `--parent-dir`,](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/) например, вот так: `svnadmin dump C:\Repositories\MY-REPOSITORY | svnadmin load C:\Repositories\TEAM-REPOSITORY --parent-dir=/path/within-repository`

- Есть альтернативный вариант, который не требует модификации pre-revprop-change хука в TEAM-REPOSITORY:

> Вы можете сделать дамп вашего репозитория с помощью команды
>
> `svnadmin dump C:\Repositories\MY-REPOSITORY > my-repository.dump`
>
> После этого полученный дамп нужно отправить администратору репозитория TEAM-REPOSITORY, попросив залить его по пути `/path/within/repository`. Voilà.